# Transaction partially failed with "Out of gas"

Tags: gnosis-safe

Gnosis Safe: https://gnosis-safe.io/app/eth:0x0792dCb7080466e4Bbc678Bdb873FE7D969832B8/balances

It has enough ether to cover gas. The transaction with nonce 75 shows up as "Failed" in Gnosis Safe, but on Etherscan it shows up as "Success": https://etherscan.io/tx/0xfc4d20c77c41c55b73ac877f63c9b686669a6431fcb1685afad9a3b5ce756cd0/advanced
However Etherscan also says `Although one or more Error Occurred [Out of gas] Contract Execution Completed`

This is using Multisend 1.1.1

The recipients have not received any of the tokens. Why did this happen? How do we prevent it from happening in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Debugging the transaction I see that there was not enough gas. Etherscan shows it as `Success` as Gnosis Safe transaction was able to end, as the Gnosis Safe stores a little gas for ending the transaction (https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/v1.3.0/contracts/GnosisSafe.sol#L176)

Please give more gas when executing the transaction

Comment: How would we increase gas? Do we need to manually specify a max gas limit when executing the transaction? Not sure how we would know what values to use

Comment: This transaction was created through a script, not the Safe interface. I can see it by the fact safeTxGas is set to 0. With the safe contracts 1.1.1, transactions with safeTxGas 0 do not revert if the internal transaction fails and it affects gas estimations. You can upgrade the contracts to version 1.3.0 or set a proper safeTxGas.